# Best way to update Android widget exactly at time?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an application with widget, and I don't need to update it periodically, besides one time exactly at 0:00:00.

So, I set **`android:updatePeriodMillis="0"`** to save device battery, but what is a best practice to do one update per day?

Comment: android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000" // (1000*60*60*24)

Comment: @BobMalooga this way it will be updated exactly at 00:00:00 every day? I thought that update time may be random...

Comment: You want an update every 24 hrs, right?

Comment: @BobMalooga no, every day exactly at 0:00:00

Comment: So... if I start it today at 00:00:00 and wait 24 hrs, when am I supposed to start it again? Don't you think that today @ 00:00:00 + 24 hrs is tomorrow @ 00:00:00?

Comment: >if I start it today at 00:00:00. This condition confuses me. User may add/remove/click widget at any time during the day, so when updatePeriod begins?

Comment: I see. Then just use an Alarm. Set it as repeating and to start at 00:00:00. And instead of sending out a notification, start the update. The problem is that, starting with KitKat, the alarm will be imprecise - so you'll have to target **API level 18**. Here's an explanation with a downloadable example (it also **survives reboots**): http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

my solution, based on [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html):

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static String ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET = "ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET";

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Widget.ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 1);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Widget.ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0));
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // do something useful here
        Toast.makeText(context, ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

widget in manifest:

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".Widget"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_metadata" />
    </receiver>
```